# JFrame listening for KeyEvent while Iconified

Tags: java, swing, focus, jframe, keyevent

How can I keep my `JFrame` listening for `KeyEvent` while its state is iconified?

For example after pressing F1 to start the program (an auto clicker) and iconify the frame (remember that because of the click the focus on the frame is lost!) :)

Comment: Please have a look at [JNativeHooks](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/), that might can help a bit, on the topic concerned , though as specified in the comments `JNI` is another alternative :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to create a key-logger program with Java, don't. It's not a good tool for creating this since it by design is isolated from the OS, in other words it's "OS-agnostic". You will need to use a different tool for your allegedly nefarious plans such as C or C++ since these languages allow you to get closer to the "metal".

Comment: Im not trying to make a keylogger, im trying to make an autoClicker, as i've mentioned :P

Comment: @AaronPriesterroth: regardless, Java isn't the right tool for this. For this to succeed with Java, you'll need JNI or JNA and C code.

Comment: Oh, that would be a shame :S I dont even know what JNI/JNA is... i think i might have to google that :)

Comment: @AaronPriesterroth: what's not to believe? Java has many strengths, chief among them is it's ability to run the same program on many platforms with little to no changes. If you have any inkling on how difficult it is to achieve this, and of the necessary sacrifice that being OS agnostic means, you will understand. It's a great tool for many jobs, but just not this one.